# How to save new and/or modified metadata with Apache Tika?

Tags: java, apache, file, metadata, apache-tika

I found this code sample. However, it does not save the new metadata. How to save the new metadata in the same file ?

I tried IOUtils copy. But the problem is that The parser implementation will consume this stream but will not close it .(https://tika.apache.org/1.1/parser.html)

I need a sample code to save the changes.

```
    public void SetMedata(File param_File) throws IOException, SAXException, TikaException {



    // parameters of parse() method
    Parser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
    BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler();
    Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
    FileInputStream inputstream = new FileInputStream(param_File);
    ParseContext context = new ParseContext();

    // Parsing the given file
    parser.parse(inputstream, handler, metadata, context);

    // list of meta data elements elements
    System.out.println("===Before=== metadata elements and values of the given file :");
    String[] metadataNamesb4 = metadata.names();

    for (String name : metadataNamesb4) {
        System.out.println(name + ": " + metadata.get(name));
    }

    // setting date meta data
    metadata.set(TikaCoreProperties.CREATED, new Date());

    // setting multiple values to author property
    metadata.set(TikaCoreProperties.TITLE, "ram ,raheem ,robin ");

    // printing all the meta data elements with new elements
    System.out.println("===After=== List of all the metadata elements  after adding new elements ");
    String[] metadataNamesafter = metadata.names();

    for (String name : metadataNamesafter) {
        System.out.println(name + ": " + metadata.get(name));
    }

    //=======================================
    //How To Save metada. ===================

}
```

Thank you in advance for your answers, examples and help.

Comment: Are you aware that Apache Tika only supports reading Metadata, and not changing it?

Comment: I thought it was possible to modify or create metadata. Then add them to the file or to a new file.

Comment: What gave you that idea? Apache Tika only supports extracting/reading metadata and content. It can save that extracted stuff to other files, but not the original

Comment: Ok, You got a source code example that illustrates your words? What do I add as a code in the above program (// How To Save metada. ===================) To write the new file with the new metadata.. Thank you

Comment: If you want the metadata saved to a new file as json, then `java -jar tika-app-1.9.jar --json foo.doc > foo.doc.json` will do you, or call similar code from your program. The App can output/save the metadata to a new text, json or xmp file